# Add class for checkout form fields in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

I want to add bootstrap `form-control` class to checkout form fields. According to woocommerce document

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
 $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'My new placeholder';
 $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'My new label';
 return $fields;
}

Each field contains an array of properties:

type – type of field (text, textarea, password, select)
label – label for the input field
placeholder – placeholder for the input
class – class for the input
required – true or false, whether or not the field is require
clear – true or false, applies a clear fix to the field/label
label_class – class for the label element
options – for select boxes, array of options (key => value pairs)
```

So technically

```
$fields['order']['order_comments']['class'] = 'form-control';
```

should work, but i get a warning

```
implode(): Invalid arguments passed
```

and the class is not being applied. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `explode()` function is expecting an array, as checkout fields `class` property uses an array.

Now for bootstrap **`form-control`** class, that need to be on the field itself, you will use undocumented **`'input_class'`** property **in an array** this way:

```
$fields['order']['order_comments']['input_class'] = array('form-control');
```

And it will work as you expect without errors (tested and works).

---

For `'class'` property, Woocommerce uses the following classes:

- `form-row-first`  (half field with on the left)
- `form-row-last` (half field with on the right)
- `form-row-wide` (full field with)

Documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: I tried using an array. Output is as shown in this screenshot https://screencast.com/t/czO2QG0C

Comment: @Arun My answer is just answering to avoid your error… `implode(): Invalid arguments passed` … Personally I don't do any theming, only just do pure development.

Comment: the new classes are not being reflected in textarea class, instead its wrapping it with <p> tag with those classes. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: @Arun Ok I found the right undocumented property to include it in the `textarea` field itself… see my updated answer. It will work for you now as you expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! there is a typo in the answer, it should be "input_class" not "imput_class"